Do duplicates in the IN statement have an impact on performance?
Say we have a table called countries with a primary key called countrycode, and the following statement:
select * from countries where countrycode in ('BE', 'FR', 'BE', 'BE');

This statement will only return 2 unique countries.
Do multiple entries in the in clause have an effect on performance? How many lookups does MySQL do? (2 or 4?) Does SQL filter out duplicates automatically?

Execute EXPLAIN select * from countries where countrycode in ('BE', 'FR', 'BE', 'BE'); to see what Mysql do, and post it to us

The extra time to test dups is insignificant compared to all the other things that are going on.  (I do believe that dups are removed, but I don't have proof, nor can I think of a way to write a test case to get the answer.)

Bit of a rude comment @BerndBuffen, why are you on stackoverflow at all then, if you cannot be helpful? I am not familiar with the EXPLAIN command, it would have been a nice answer to the question. It's like answering "just google it", to every question.

@BerndBuffen, explain does not give me information about the amount of lookups.

Modern database optimizers are smart enough to recognize that 'BE' appears multiple times and will treat the duplicates as a single instance.
MySQL will likely build an execution plan where it scans for 'BE' and 'FR' without being influenced by the repetition.
MySQL effectively performs 2 lookups in this case, despite the presence of 4 values.
SQL does not filter out duplicates automatically before execution, but the optimizer handles them efficiently.
